# Extracting information from an xml

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I scraped a website that required login yesterday, the page is xml format like below. I got into trouble parsing it since some of the teachers belongs to two departments, plus I don't need the first three lines cause that only means I login successfully. I need to turn it into a data frame (or list, json format)

My code:

```
ID <- xpathApply(xml, "//teacher[@id]")
ID_unlist <- unlist(ID)
matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(ID_unlist),nrow= 2, byrow=TRUE)

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  first argument must be atomic
```

XML:

```
<result status="success">
  <code>1</code>
  <note>success</note>
  <teacherList>
    <teacher id="D95">
      <name>Mary</name>
      <department id="420">
        <name>Math</name>
      </department>
      <department id="421">
        <name>Statistics</name>
      </department>
    </teacher>
    <teacher id="D73">
      <name>Adam</name>
      <department id="412">
        <name>English</name>
      </department>
    </teacher>
  </teacherList>
</result>
```

And the result I expected will be:

```
t_id      teacher       d_id   department
 D95         Mary        420         Math
 D95         Mary        421   statistics
 D73         Adam        412      English
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way, but works.

```
require(XML)
content_list <- XML::xmlToList(content)
df<-as.data.frame ( do.call(rbind,
    lapply(content_list$teacherList, function(teacher) { 
      unname ( do.call(cbind, list ( teacher$.attrs, teacher$name,  do.call(rbind, teacher[names(teacher) == "department"]) ) )  )
    }) 
  )
)
colnames(df)<-c("id","teacher","department","did")


   id teacher department did
1 D95    Mary       Math 420
2 D95    Mary Statistics 421
3 D73    Adam    English 412
```